# How can I determine what size pressure pump and tank do I need?

Tags: plumbing

we have a cistern tank that is 3 meters deep , the desired pump would have to pull the water from the cistern (vertical distance is 3 meters) then the water would be pushed horizontally for about 22 to 25 meters)   then vertically to the overhead tank which is 21 meters high.  What size pump in HP would be good plus the size of the pressure tank.

Comment: What volume of water do you require?

Comment: If you have an overhead tank that's 21m high, what do you want a pressure tank for? In general the whole point of an elevated storage tank is that it serves the same purpose as a pressure tank...

Comment: Sir, the cistern tank is under the ground.  The water from the cistern tank which is 3 meters under the ground needs to be pumped up to the overhead tank.  I am in the Philippines.  That is the requirement to have a reservoir.  Now from the overhead tank, gravity is the one which would give it pressure to supply the lower floors.  The overhead tank is composed of 2 , 2500gallon tanks with float valves.

Comment: You don't need a pressure tank, you can literally just have a submersible or jet pump go into a pipe that is open at the other end. Probably not a bad idea to have a check valve if there's not one in the pump since otherwise the water in the pipe will drain back when turned off (not a big deal, just means it'll take longer when the pump does come on). The pump would be controlled by a float switch.

Comment: To answer your question, in order to size a pump you need to know the total dynamic head (TDH) and the flow rate you want. TDH is basically the vertical distance you're pumping, plus friction loss from the pipe. Friction loss depends on size of pipe plus flow rate. For example, if you want 13 US GPM through a 1" poly pipe, you're looking at TDH of about 91 ft (28 meters) -- there are charts for this. Looking at a couple pump sizing curves, looks like a 1/2 HP pump would work (but you need to check the curves for the pump you want to use, based on your TDH, flow rate and pipe size).